# SpringBoot : ServletContext resource cannot resolve S3 URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-aws

I'm developing a Spring Boot application in which I'm integrating Amazon S3 service. 
 This class is my repository to access the S3 bucket :

```
public class S3FileRepository implements ImageRepository {

private String bucket;
private AmazonS3 s3Client;
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public S3FileRepository(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, AmazonS3 s3Client, String bucket) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    this.s3Client = s3Client;
    this.bucket = bucket;
}

private static String toS3Uri(String bucket, String imageName) {
    return String.format("s3://%s/%s", bucket, imageName);
}

@Override
public Resource getImage(String name) {
    return resourceLoader.getResource(S3FileRepository.toS3Uri(this.bucket, name).concat(this.IMAGE_EXTENSION));
}
```

using [Spring Boot Autoconfiguration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration) as suggested.
 So in my `pom.xml`, among other things, I've

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Moreover I've an `application.properties` done like this:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey= (mykey)
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey= (mysecret)
cloud.aws.credentials.instanceProfile=true
cloud.aws.region.static=eu-west-2
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
```

#### The problem:

Everything works fine if i compile my project and then I simply run the JAR with `java -jar target/myproject.jar`, i correctly get the image that I ask for and everything is fine.

Instead **if I run the project with** the *IDE default* **`mvn spring-boot:run`** when I try to get an image (present in the bucket) **an Exception occour** saying following:

```
    ServletContext resource [/s3://mybucket/test.jpeg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/s3://mybucket/test.jpeg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

So what **I think** is that it throws an Exception because it's like **it goes inside the jar** to look for something that match `s3://mybucket/test.jpeg` but I can't get why, and why it happens only running the project with `mvn spring-boot:run` and not running the jar.

Comment: You'll need to specify both which IDE and the full stack trace of the error. (Note that unless you're needing to process the image locally it's a lot easier on everyone for you to just return an HTTP S3 URI to the client; jets3t makes generating signed URIs simpler.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely hitting the `spring-cloud-aws` issue [#384](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/384) whereupon the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency, which is activated when you start the application from the IDE, activates a different code path in resource loading.

You can test whether you're hitting this issue by removing the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency from your `pom.xml` file, reloading the project in your IDE, and running the same test.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between app's launching with "java -jar" and "mvn spring-boot:run". From Spring Boot docs: "The Spring Boot Maven plugin includes a run goal that can be used to quickly compile and run your application. **Applications run in an exploded form**, as they do in your IDE". It can be a reason of problem.